# Deriving deletion-contraction formula from Subgraph Expansion of Chromatic Polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, the [*chromatic polynomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Chromatic_polynomial) $P(G,q)$ counts the number of [$q$-colorings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring) of a graph $G$. It satisfies the deletion-contraction formula:
\begin{equation*}
P(G,q) = P(G-e, q) - P(G/e, q)
\end{equation*}
where $e$ is any edge from $E$ and $G-e$ is obtained by deleting an edge $e$ from $G$ while $G/e$ is obtained by contracting $e$ in $G$.

This is easy to prove: For an edge $e=(u,v)$ in $G$, a proper coloring requires the adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ to have different colors.

1. $P(G-e,q)$ counts the number of $q$-colorings but in this case $u$ and $v$ may have the same color because $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent.
2. To compensate the improper colorings, subtract the number of $q$-colorings with $u$ and $v$ having the same color. This corresponds to subtracting $P(G/e,q)$ because if $u$ and $v$ have the same color then they can be merged into one vertex with the same color.

Combining these two cases immediately yields the recurrence above.

---

Now, I'm just curious whether we can get the same recurrence from a subgraph expansion of chromatic polynomial. A chromatic polynomial can be written as

\begin{equation*}
P(G,q) = \sum_{X\subseteq E}(-1)^{|X|}q^{k(X)}
\end{equation*}
where the summation runs over all the possible subsets $X$ of edges $E$ in $G$ and $k(X)$ is the number of connected components of a subgraph induced by $X$. This is easily obtained from [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).
If I want to derive deletion-contraction formula from the subgraph expansion, I may begin with a new edge set $E'=E- \{e\}$ and break down the summation as follows:

\begin{equation*}
P(G,q) = \sum_{X\subseteq E'}(-1)^{|X|}q^{k(X)} + \sum_{X\subseteq E'}(-1)^{|X|+1}q^{k(X\cup\{e\})}
\end{equation*}
There's nothing fancy in these summations: The first runs over the edge set which *doesn't* contain $e$ and the second over those which contains $e$. Handling the extra $-1$ in the second summation, I see that the first summation must yield $P(G-e,q)$ while the second $P(G/e,q)$. The first one is straightforward, but I'm not sure about the second.

**Question**

1. What's the best way to prove that the second summation is actually $P(G/e,q)?$ Is it even possible?
2. Is there any textbook / paper which derives deletion-contraction from subgraph expansion?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is quite easy to see explicitly that the second term is $P(G/e,q)$. Consider $F\subset E$ with $e\in F$ (in your notation, $F=X\cup\{e\}$ for $X\subset E'$). Now consider the edge set $\tilde F$ obtained by doing the contraction of the edge $e$, i.e. by removing $e$ and identifying the endpoints. Then it is quite obvious that $|\tilde F| = |F|+1$, as you also have noticed. On the other hand this contraction operation does not change the number of connected components, so $k(F) = k(\tilde F)$. We can then observe that any subset of the edges of $G/e$ can be obtained this way, so clearly
   $$ P(G/e,q) = \sum_{\tilde F\subset \tilde E} (-1)^{|\tilde F|} q^{k(\tilde F)} =  \sum_{F\subset E} (-1)^{|F|+1} q^{k(F)} = - \sum_{F\subset E} (-1)^{|F|} q^{k(F)},$$
   which is exactly what you wanted to prove.
2. I do not know any. Since the deletion-contraction formula can be proven from the quite simple observation that $P(G,q) = P(G+e,q) + P(G\cdot e, q)$, the one you propose seems a more complex route to get to the result.

   (I say more complex because one needs to first show that $P(G,q)$ is actually equal to $\sum_{F\subset E} (-1)^{|F|} q^{k(F)}$, but of course if one chooses to start by defining it in this way -as a specialization of the Tutte polynomial for example- and then proving the connection to graph coloring, then this is probably a more direct way.)